# Increment file everytime script is called C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arduino, serial-port

I am calling this script from a unity project. At this point what I am trying to do is increment the file every time the script is called.

So once it is called it reads the data saves the data in a file.

Right now it only makes a file `alpha0.csv` and doesn't print a new file if I call the script again.

Can anyone guide me on how to fix this issue.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;
using System.Management;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class ArduinoControl : MonoBehaviour
{

    SerialPort arduino;
    public string portName = "COM5";
    public static bool status ;
    public string test = "alpha";
    private static int counter;
    private static int lineCount;
    private static string receivedstring = string.Empty;

    void Start()
    {
        arduino = new SerialPort(portName, 115200);
        arduino.Open();
        status = true;     
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (arduino.IsOpen)
        {
            if (status)  // (& UnityCommand = "F")  
            {
                arduino.Write("s");
                arduino.ReadTimeout = 5000;
                arduino.WriteTimeout = 5000;
                receivedstring += arduino.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
                arduino.BaseStream.Flush();
                lineCount++;
                if(lineCount >= 10 && receivedstring != null)
                {
                    WriteOutputToTextFile(test,receivedstring); // Write to csv here...
                    status = false;
                }
                arduino.BaseStream.Flush();

             }

        }
    }


    //private static int counter;
    static void WriteOutputToTextFile(string path,string _data)
    {
        string FolderName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);   //set destination as your desktop
        using (StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter($"{FolderName }\\{path}{counter}.csv", false))
         {
            SW.WriteLine(_data);
            SW.Close();
        }
        counter++;
        lineCount = 0;
        receivedstring = string.Empty;
    }


}
```

Comment: Do you mean by "call the script" again the whole posted program -if thats the case the var counter is locally defined, so every time you call it it starts with 0. You need a global var in the calling/main programm or you count the files in the dir and set counter to the next highest number files_in_dir +1

Comment: can you give me an example main function in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly you want to create a new file with the correct numerical suffix, as in `alpha0.csv`, `alpha1.csv`, `alpha2.csv`...
This can actually be a bit of a pain to do, you could use a variable in a wider scope as comments suggest but as you are saving this to disk I assume you want this to work correctly even between starting and stopping your program.

---

I would suggest

1. Make sure all your files are in their own folder
2. Read in all of the file names
3. Run a 'find max' algorithm on the suffixes in your folder
4. Add 1 to this and use that to create your new file

---

Reading in file names can be done in Unity like so:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("/*your directory*/");
FileInfo[] fileInfos = dir.GetFiles("*.csv");
```

---

Then for getting the next suffix

```
static readonly string rootName = "Alpha";
int maxFileNumber = 0;
foreach (var f in fileInfos)
{
    string tempName = f.Name;
    tempName = tempName.Substring(0, tempName.Length - ".csv".Length); // remove .csv
    int lengthOfNumber = tempName.Length - rootName.Length; // get the length of the number at the end of the name
    nextFileNumber = int.Parse(tempName.Substring(rootName.Length, lengthOfNumber)); // get the number at the end of the name
    maxFileNumber = nextFileNumber > maxFileNumber ? nextRoomNumber : maxRoomNumber; // find max alorithm
}
nextFileNumber += 1; // next number
string newFileName = rootName + ToString(nextFileNumber)+".csv";
```

Comment: If I were to do that with my current code can you show me how that would be done?

Comment: Edited to better explain, hope this is helpful